# Eloquent model inside directory prevents resource visibility in Nova navigation

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I am running into a weird issue. I am on Nova `2.12` and Laravel `6.18` and Composer `2`. I have a `Salon` model inside `Models` directory. On the `Salon` resource in the `Nova` folder, I have this line     `public static $model = 'App\\Models\\Salon';`.

This somehow prevents the `Salon` resource from showing up in the navigation. No errors are thrown however. Note, `User` resource does show up fine, and I think its because `User` eloquent model is out of the `Models` directory. Any clue what's happening?

Comment: Can you check your `Salon` resource whether it has set `$displayInNavigation` to  `false`